# How to analyse dataframe with character columns using multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have a mixed database in excel which has a numeric and characters columns.

The final outcome should be various plots that describe my research question which is if there is any connection between district, job sector and more to unemployments percentage.
I did a lot of searching and nothing comes up as far as it comes to characters columns.
So, I need your help in understanding how can I make a conditional command to create a subset of this database which summarise it.

Here's how the database looks like:

```
     Cdata <-
  structure(
    list(
      Month = c(
        "2020-01",
        "2020-01",
        "2020-01",
        "2020-01",
        "2020-01",
        "2020-01",
        "2020-01",
        "2020-01",
        "2020-01",
        "2020-01"
      ),
      District = c(
        "Center",
        "Center",
        "Center",
        "Center",
        "Center",
        "Center",
        "Center",
        "Center",
        "Center",
        "Center"
      ),
      Age = c(
        "Under 17",
        "Under 17",
        "Under 17",
        "18-24",
        "18-24",
        "18-24",
        "18-24",
        "18-24",
        "18-24",
        "18-24"
      ),
      Gender = c(
        "Male",
        "Male",
        "Female",
        "Male",
        "Male",
        "Male",
        "Male",
        "Male",
        "Male",
        "Male"
      ),
      Education = c("0",
                    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
      MedicalDisability = c(
        "Without any",
        "Without any",
        "Without any",
        "Without any",
        "Without any",
        "Without any",
        "Without any",
        "Without any",
        "Without any",
        "Without any"
      ),
      Religion = c(
        "Jewish",
        "Muslims",
        "Other",
        "Jewish",
        "Jewish",
        "Jewish",
        "Jewish",
        "Jewish",
        "Jewish",
        "Jewish"
      ),
      UneploymentDays = c(
        "0-30",
        "Over 270",
        "Over 270",
        "0-30",
        "0-30",
        "0-30",
        "0-30",
        "0-30",
        "0-30",
        "31-180"
      ),
      Occupation = c(
        "Laboring class",
        "Sales \\ Costumer service",
        "Undefinded",
        "Laboring class",
        "Academic degree",
        "Practical engineers / Technicians",
        "Undefinded",
        "Sales \\ Costumer service",
        "Laboring class",
        "Practical engineers / Technicians"
      ),
      Jobseekers = c(2L,
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L),
      GMI = c(0L, 0L, 0L,
              0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
      ACU = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
              0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
      NACU = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
               2L, 5L, 2L),
      NewSeekers = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
                     0L, 0L),
      NewFiredSeekers = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
                          0L, 0L, 0L)
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, 10L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

i need a new dataset that looks like this:

```
District    Jobseekers  GMI     ACU     NACU
North       1024        8710    3245    3256
Center      57691       12160   8710    14320
South       21516       9821    5289    18172
```

And than sort it all over again by age:

```
Age       Jobseekers    GMI     ACU     NACU
Under 17  1024          8710    3245    3256
18-24     57691         12160   8710    14320
25-34     21516         9821    5289    18172
45-54     4682          7142    2365    6128
55-64     1999          1991    2839    1927
Over 64   10918         4289    1378    5368
```

From that point, i need to create various plots which describe how many females\males from north district is unemployed, and than make a statistic tests (such as wilcoxon for instance) and show my conclusions (is there any connection between gender and unemployment \ if officers keep they jobs more than working class)

Mainly i look for the best technique to work with this dataframe and get my result. All of my colleagues work with a numeric dataframe so that make their lives much easier.

Hope i made my point clearly.
as for the codes, I've tried so many structures and examples, non of them really helped. 
Let me make it clear - I don't want you to do my work or write the whole code for me, but at the same time I'll mentioned I'm a newbie in R language, and i do this task as a part of a project in data science course.
If anything else needed, please let me know.

Here's a screenshot of the database: 
[image]

Thanks,
Moshe

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `aggregate(cbind(Jobseekers, GMI, ACU, NACU) ~ District, Cdata, sum)` and `aggregate(cbind(Jobseekers, GMI, ACU, NACU) ~ Age, Cdata, sum)`?

Comment: And maybe code the character values into numerical values, if the characters confuse you. For example in the Religion column: Jewish = 1, Muslim = 2, Other = 3 etc.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! the first one is the exact outcome i expected. now i need to understand how to plot multipe values or conditional values  (such as unemployed people from the north). it's not posible to convert characters into numbers because some columns contains more than 10 options and the whole document is more than 100K rows. Appreciate your help again!